# Move a file that user chooses to another directory

Tags: c++, file, rename

I'm trying to make a program that moves a file (like `file.txt`) specified by the user to a directory that he also specifies. I tried using the `move()` function, however I don't quite understand it yet, so I tried with the [`rename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) function and used [this site](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstdio/rename)'s code as help.

**I've worked with the `rename()` function and moved a file like this**:

```
char oldDir[] = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\file.txt";
char newDir[] = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\New folder\\file.txt";

if (rename(oldDir, newDir) != 0)
    perror("Error moving file");
else
    cout << "File moved successfully";
```

And that worked perfectly, if I typed in the directory correctly. The thing is that I would like to tell the user to type in the directory of a file to move to another directory, so I tried this:

```
char oldDir[] = " ";
char newDir[] = " ";
cout << "Type file directory: "; cin >> oldDir;
cout << "Type file directory to move to: "; cin >> newDir;
if (rename(oldDir, newDir) != 0)
    perror("Error moving file");
else
    cout << "File moved successfully";
```

But, when typing in the console the `oldDir` path like: `C:\\Users\\MyName\\file.txt`, I always get the error:

> Error moving file no such file or directory

It returns before I can even type the `newDir` path. Of course the `file.txt` is in `C:\Users\MyName`.

What could be the problem? I tried to remove the `" "` from the `oldDir` and `newDir` variables, but then I get another error:

> incomplete type is not allowed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `char oldDir[] = " ";` provides storage for exactly 2 `char`s (the space and the 0-terminator). If somebody types more than one character `oldDir` is not a sufficient storage. (The same for `newDir`.) I urgently recommend to use `std::string` instead. (You can access the raw C string with `std::string::c_str()` to use it in `rename()`.)

Comment: Take a look at the "cin and strings" section of https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: For the record: What makes `char oldDir[]` a complete type _is_ the initialization with `" "` because the compiler determines how large the array has to become to store `" "`. Hence, removing the initialization doesn't work. Of course, you could provide the exact number in the brackets instead but I still recommend to use `std::string` instead of a C `char` array.

Comment: @Scheff So I've changed the variables `char oldDir` and `newDir` to `string oldDir` and `newDir` and then added .c_str() in the if statement, I've run the program and typed in the directories of that file.txt and I've got error saying that  **"File exists"** even though I want to move the file and not create or whatever that error wants me to say.                                                     `if (rename(oldDir.c_str(), newDir.c_str()) != 0)`

Comment: 1.) Your change made the program running. 2.) "File exists" sounds to me like a response from the OS. So, have a look at [MS doc.: rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/rename-wrename?view=msvc-160) what it could mean. I assume your error is `EACCES`: _File or directory specified by newname already exists or could not be created (invalid path); or oldname is a directory and newname specifies a different path._ Are you sure that you used a path for the newname which isn't already occupied (from a previous test)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't double up on the slashes when typing them in at the command prompt at runtime, if that is what you are doing.  Escaping slashes only applies to [*string literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in code, not runtime data.

That said, you are not allocating enough memory to hold the user's input.  When initialized with `" "`, your `oldDir[]` and `newDir[]` arrays are each only 2 `char`s in size.  When you drop the `" "`, the compiler no longer knows how large to make the array, since you are not telling it which size to use.

You need to handle the arrays more like this instead:

```cpp
char oldDir[MAX_PATH] = "";
char newDir[MAX_PATH] = "";

std::cout << "Type file directory: ";
cin.getline(oldDir, MAX_PATH); // paths can contain spaces!

std::cout << "Type file directory to move to: ";
cin.getline(newDir, MAX_PATH); // paths can contain spaces!

if (rename(oldDir, newDir) != 0)
    perror("Error moving file");
else
    std::cout << "File moved successfully" << std::endl;
```

However, you really should be using `std::string` instead:

```cpp
std::string oldDir, newDir;

std::cout << "Type file directory: ";
std::getline(cin, oldDir); // paths can contain spaces!

std::cout << "Type file directory to move to: ";
std::getline(cin, newDir); // paths can contain spaces!

if (rename(oldDir.c_str(), newDir.c_str()) != 0)
    perror("Error moving file");
else
    std::cout << "File moved successfully" << std::endl;
```

If you are using C++17 or later, consider using [`std::filesystem::rename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) instead of [`::rename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rename):

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

std::string oldDir, newDir;

std::cout << "Type file directory: ";
std::getline(cin, oldDir); // paths can contain spaces!

std::cout << "Type file directory to move to: ";
getline(cin, newDir); // paths can contain spaces!

std::error_code err;
std::filesystem::rename(oldDir, newDir, err);
if (err)
    std::cerr << "Error moving file: " << err.message() << endl;
else
    std::cout << "File moved successfully" << std::endl;
```

Comment: So I tried the code with C++ 17 and when typing in the directories (old and new) like this: C:\Users\MyName\file.txt and then C:\Users\MyName\New folder  , The folder named "New folder" gets the name of that "file.txt" . A bit weird because it still says it's a folder and I can enter it. Could you please try to use that code ? Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You can't omit the filename in `newDir` if `oldDir` has a filename. The `std::filesystem::rename()` doc says: "*If `old_p` is a non-directory file, then `new_p` **must be** one of: - the same file as `old_p` or a hardlink to it ...; existing non-directory file ...; non-existing file in an existing directory.*" Even the C `rename()` doc says: "*If the `old` argument points to the pathname of a file that is not a directory, the `new` argument **shall not** point to the pathname of a directory.*" So, to preserve the filename, `newDir` would have to be `C:\Users\MyName\New folder\file.txt` instead